# Conditional Rendering in Styled Component based on Parents' Props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

How would I go about applying conditional styles to a Styled Component based on its parent component's props?

A high-level sample setup of my current code is below:

```
// File 1: GrandParent.js

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Parent from './parent';

export default function GrandParent() {
    const [ isExpanded, setIsExpanded ] = useState(false);

    render (
        <>
            <Parent isExpanded={isExpanded} />
            ...other Stuff
        </>
    );
}
```

```
// File 2: Parent.js

import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import mediaQueries from './settings';

export default function Parent(props) {
    render (
        <div className={props.isExpanded ? `expanded` : ``}>
            ... other stuff
            <Child>I'm a child.</Child>
        </>
    );
}

const Child = styled.div`
    background-color: "red";

    .expanded & {
        background-color: "blue";

        ${mediaQueries.desktop`
            background-color: "navy";
        `}
    }
`;
```

Essentially, what I'd like is for my `<Child>` styled component to have awareness of it's `<Parent>`'s props so that I can style it conditionally. Currently, I am just conditionally applying a class name to a div just inside the `<Parent>`, and then I'm using that class name to apply styling to the `<Child>`. But doesn't feel like a very Styled Components or React way of doing things.

What I'd like to be able to do is something more like this:

```
const Child = styled.div`
    background-color: ${props => props.isExpanded ? 'blue' : 'red'};
`;
```

But is there a way for me to do this without having to pass in 'isExpanded' as a prop on the `<Child>`? In my actual code, there are many more children of `<Parent>` who will also need to know the status of 'isExpanded' for styling purposes, and I really don't want to have to pass that prop to all of them individually.

I think Context API might be the key here, but I'm already using a context several levels higher up above `GrandParent` in the React tree for global style settings, and I'm afraid that if I try to nest a 2nd context (perhaps wrapping it around `<Parent>` to let `<Parent>` and all of its children know about the status of 'isExpanded'), that then both `<Parent>` and `<Child>` might lose access to the outer context... or is that not how context nesting works?

I just know that I still need both `<Parent>` and `<Child>` to have access to some theme settings from the outer context. And I don't know if it's overkill to introduce a 2nd context at the `<Parent>` level just for keeping track of the status of that single 'isExpanded' prop.

The other requirement here is that I need `<Child>` to be able to handle media queries within its conditional styling as well (eg. only applying certain styles if 'isExpanded' is true and if it's a desktop viewport).

What's the proper way to set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. Context is the way to go.

Context is designed to be a lightweight cross-component data store and using 2 contexts in this case is definitely not overkill; In fact, this use case is almost exactly what Context was created for. (Anecdotally, at work we use dozens of nested contexts).

```
export const ExpandedContext = createContext();
export default function GrandParent() {
    const [ isExpanded, setIsExpanded ] = useState(false);
    
    render (
        <ExpandedContext.Provider value={{ isExpanded }}>
            <Parent />
            ...other Stuff
        <ExpandedContext.Provider/>
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to access context inside of a styled-component, so you'll have to pass in the value via props instead.

```
export default function Parent(props) {
    const { isExpanded } = useContext(ExpandedContext);
    render (
        <div>
            ... other stuff
            <Child isExpanded={isExpanded}>I'm a child.</Child>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and example setup! Just so I'm understanding correctly though, I can wrap the <Parent> in this new context, but I still wouldn't be able to access this context's value via the <Child> styled component? Darn. So in these cases, if you've got a lot of child styled components that need conditional styling, it'd be considered normal to potentially end up with a lot of prop(s) getting passed down just for the sake of conditional styling? How much of an anti-pattern would it be considered if I were to leave the current .expanded class dependency in place?

Comment: If the Child component is a component that gets used a lot then wrap the styled-component in a normal component called Child and change the existing child to StyledChild. Then you can use context in the normal component and pass it into the styled-component. This way you don’t have to pass in props so many times.

Comment: Okay. I will keep that in mind then. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could make the parent's container `div` a styled component and [refer](https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#referring-to-other-components) to `Child`. Something like:

```
export default function Parent(props) {
    render (
        <ParentContainer isExpanded={props.isExpanded}>
            ... other stuff
            <Child>I'm a child.</Child>
        </ParentContainer>
    );
}

const Child = styled.div`
    // ...
`;

const ParentContainer = styled.div`
  > ${Child} {
    background-color: ${props => props.isExpanded ? 'blue' : 'red'};
  }
`;
```